# CSS Horizontal list fitting inside UL with variable widths

Tags: css, list, horizontallist

Is there a better way to code a horizontal list where list items are variable and last list item aligns right.  I have set it up so that word breaks in center for long text items.

PROS:

- Everything is on same line
- Fits in UL

CONS:

- Word break, in the event of, text is hard to read
- Hacked LI first-child to float left in order to collapse its width

This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandraqu/adwkx6Lf/)!

```
<ul class="horizontal">
    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-3x"></i>
    </li>
    <li>My Title
        <br/>
        <a href="#" class="break-all" title="This long title - 9" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">This long title - 9</a>
        <span>(87)</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Change</a>
    </li>
</ul>

ul.horizontal {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}

ul.horizontal > li {
list-style:none;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:top;
margin:0;
padding:2px;
}
ul.horizontal > li:first-child {
float:left;
}
ul.horizontal > li:last-child {
width:1%;
}
ul.horizontal > li > a {
outline:none;
text-decoration:underline;
color: #444;
}
ul.horizontal > li.vertical-middle {
line-height: 40px;
}
.break-all{ 
word-break:break-all;
}

/* misc */
ul {
font: normal 0.9em/1.5em arial, geneva, sans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there's `flexbox` of course.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

li {
  flex:1;
  border:1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

li:first-child,
li:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  text-align:left;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="horizontal">
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-3x"></i>
  </li>
  <li><p>My Title</p>
    <a href="#" class="break-all" title="This long title - 9" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">This long title - 9</a>
    <span>(87)</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Change</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes.  We are supporting IE9.  I would have to use Modernizr.  I'll give that a test.